# How is this hash getting its keys?

Tags: ruby

Okay so this is just an answer to one of the practice problems I'm working on and I'm confused on what's exactly going on.

It's basically getting the number of each letter in a `str` (`String`) and ignoring the whitespaces.

I get that counts begins as an empty hash but how does it ever get the letters as keys in it? `counts[char] += 1` I am guessing is somehow entering both the key (letters) and the value (number of repeats) into the hash?

```
    def letter_count(str)
      counts = Hash.new(0)

      str.each_char do |char|
        counts[char] += 1 unless char == " "
      end
      counts
    end
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. I dont get how the counts is getting its keys. I can see that the values of each key is changed with += 1, but how is the hash getting the letters to use as keys?

Comment: Hash can use everything as key. Including letters (i.e. one-char strings).

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning, counts is an empty hash with 0 as a default value. So if we'll try to get value for key that is currently absent in the hash, 0 is returned.

Then there is a cycle over each char in a string. The char is treated as a key for the hash (but if char is a space, it do nothing). We get value currently stored in hash (or 0 if it is absent) and increment it.

So for string 'as a' we will get this answer:

```
{'a' => 2, 's' => 1}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new The 0 in Hash.new(0) sets the default value as 0 for each element. The counts[char] will create an element with key "char" (initialised to the default) if it does not already exist

Comment: okay reuben thanks so much for this. This is exactly what I trying to figure out

Comment: @ReubenMallaby more precisely, `counts[char]` returns the default value if the key does not exists, without creating it. `+=` causes the key to be created by calling [`Hash#[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D)